# analysis problem proof with derivative

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

$f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is a continuous function and $0 < a < b$ and $f$ is differentiable in $(a,b)$ and $\dfrac{f(a)}{a} = \dfrac{f(b)}{b}$.

Prove that there exists $x \in (a,b)$ so that $xf'(x) = f(x)$.

Comment: It should also be assumed that $f$ is continuous at the endpoints.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint**: Apply the mean value theorem (or Rolle's theorem) to $g(x) = \dfrac{f(x)}{x}$.

Comment: Or just Rolle's theorem.

Comment: @MichaelHardy That would work too.

Comment: OK, so
$\frac{\frac{f(b)}{b} - \frac{f(a)}{a}}{b-a}$ = $\frac{f'(x)}{x}$
And I have got 0 in the numerator. Don't know what to do next.

Comment: @keri Differentiation should be applied to all of $\dfrac{f(x)}{x}$. In other words, take $\left(\dfrac{f(x)}{x}\right)' = 0$. Apply the quotient rule and simplify to get the result.

Comment: Aghh so true! My mistake.
$\frac{\frac{f(b)}{b} - \frac{f(a)}{a}}{b-a}$ = ($\frac{f(x)}{x}$)' = $\frac{f'(x)-f(x)}{x^2}$  soooo  
f(x) = xf'(x)
Thank you so much! Now, it is clear! :)

Comment: @keri Happy to help!

Comment: Rolle's theorem (sing to the tune of Goldfinger).....